# Google Maps Android API: display marks saved in db

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to google maps android api, and there is one thing I want to know about it: can it display marks (points, items, as you wish) whose coordinates are saved in db? Say, I mark my location on the map during a day, it is saved in database, and finally, in the end of a day, I can view all the points that I've been to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query your database and use that information to populate an `ItemizedOverlay` (Maps V1) or to create a series of markers (Maps V2), as you see fit.

Comment: @Zapadlo: At least with Maps V1, having lots of overlay items would slow down panning and zooming performance. Having dozens of items is fine; having hundreds of items might be an issue. I have not tested how many markers Maps V2 can handle, but I will be surprised if it is significantly less. Maps V2 also makes it easier for you to track when the map boundaries change due to pan and zoom events, which gives you opportunities to perhaps add/remove markers to only have relevant markers on the map at any one time, improving performance.